Algoritmo por inserción en código SL
Tengo este código en lenguaje SL que pretende implementar el algoritmo por inserción de elementos de una lista
programa OrdenarArreglo
constantes
    N = 12 // Número total de elementos
variables
    arre : matriz[N] numerico
    i, j, temp : numerico
inicio
   
    // Inicializar el arreglo
    arre[1] = 5
    arre[2] = 3
    arre[3] = 0
    arre[4] = 2
    arre[5] = 4
    arre[6] = 1
    arre[7] = 0
    arre[8] = 5
    arre[9] = 2
    arre[10] = 3
    arre[11] = 1
    arre[12] = 4
    
    /*
     resultado esperado
     0
     0
     1
     1
     2
     2
     3
     3
     4
     4
     5
     5
     */

    cls()

    // Imprimir arreglo original
    desde i = 1 hasta N {
        imprimir("Antes: ", arre[i],"\n")
    }
    
    imprimir("\n")    
    
    // Algoritmo de ordenamiento por inserción
    desde i = 2 hasta N {
        temp = arre[i]  // Guardar el valor actual
        j = i - 1       // Comenzar a comparar con el elemento anterior
        
        // Mover elementos de arre[1..i-1] que son mayores que temp
        mientras ((j > 1) and (arre[j] > temp)) {
            arre[j + 1] = arre[j] // Mover el elemento hacia adelante
            j = j - 1             // Mover hacia atrás
        }
        
        arre[j + 1] = temp  // Insertar el elemento en su posición correcta
    }
    
    // Imprimir arreglo ordenado
    desde i = 1 hasta N {
        imprimir("Después: ", arre[i], "\n")
    }
fin

resultado esperado
Después: 0
Después: 0
Después: 1
Después: 1
Después: 2
Después: 2
Después: 3
Después: 3
Después: 4
Después: 4
Después: 5
Después: 5
resultado obtenido
Después: 5
Después: 0
Después: 1
Después: 1
Después: 2
Después: 2
Después: 3
Después: 3
Después: 4
Después: 4
Después: 5
El pseudocódigo SL no permite que j valga 0 ni 1 en el Mientras. ¿Qué alternativa puedo obtener para que el primer elemento escrito se posicione al final?

Eso no es "pseudo-codigo"; es "código", pues lo puedes ejecutar tal como está escrito.

Gracias por este comentario, realmente me ayudo a resolver el problema con el algoritmo.

Iba a trabajar en él, pero como ya lo resolviste, puedes cerrar la pregunta.

Pensé que estaba corregido, pero no, sigue dando un lugar corrido

Disculpa, pero que es maruga, porque lo pones como palabra clave?

Es un compilador de pseudocódigo, que resubí a internet

No encuentro información del compilador o pseudocódigo en ningún lado, asi que he de suponer que es una limitante del código o compilador nada mas. Solución como tal no hay.

Pones Maruga Script en internet y el primer resultado de Internet Archive es la página para descargarlo. Yo lo resubí

Tienes un sutil error en el algoritmo:
// Algoritmo de ordenamiento por inserción
Para i = 2 Hasta N Hacer
inicio
      // "temp" lo colocamos en el "Mientras"
      // temp = arre[i];  // Guardar el valor actual
      // cambiamos el valor de "j"        
    j = i; // Comenzar a comparar con el elemento anterior
    
      // Mover elementos de arre[1..i-1] que son mayores que temp
      // modificamos la condición
    Mientras( j > 1) Y ( arre[ j - 1 ] > temp ) Hacer
    inicio
          // modificamos el valor pasado a "temp"
        temp = arre[ j ];  // Guardar el valor actual
          // modificamos las asignaciones
        arre[ j ] = arre[ j - 1 ]; // Mover el elemento hacia adelante
        arre[ j - 1 ] = temp;              // Mover hacia atrás
    Fin 
    Para i = 1 Hasta N Hacer
    inicio
       Escribir "Después: ", arre[i], nl;
    Fin
Fin


¿y dónde está el valor inicial de temp?

dentro del while.

Tienes un error en esta condición:
 Mientras (j > 1) Y (arre[j] > temp) Hacer

Lo que estás haciendo es recorrer cada elemento del arreglo pero como el primer índice en maruga es 1, nunca llegas hasta el inicio.
Se corrige facilmente cambiando el > por un >=.
Esta es la versión corregida en pseint, ya que maruga no funciona en mi computadora.
Proceso OrdenarArreglo
    Definir N, arre Como Entero;
    N <- 12;
    Dimension arre[N];
    Definir i, j, temp Como Entero;
    // Inicializar el arreglo
    arre[0] <- 5;
    arre[1] <- 3;
    arre[2] <- 0;
    arre[3] <- 2;
    arre[4] <- 4;
    arre[5] <- 1;
    arre[6] <- 0;
    arre[7] <- 5;
    arre[8] <- 2;
    arre[9] <- 3;
    arre[10] <- 1;
    arre[11] <- 4;
    
    // Imprimir arreglo original
    Para i <- 0 Hasta N-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "Antes: ", arre[i];
    FinPara
    
    Escribir ""; // Línea en blanco
    
    // Algoritmo de ordenamiento por inserción
    Para i <- 1 Hasta N-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        temp <- arre[i];  // Guardar el valor actual
        j <- i - 1;       // Comenzar a comparar con el elemento anterior
        
        // Mover elementos de arre[0..i-1] que son mayores que temp
        Mientras (j >= 0) Y (arre[j] > temp) Hacer
            arre[j + 1] <- arre[j]; // Mover el elemento hacia adelante
            j <- j - 1;             // Mover hacia atrás
        FinMientras
        
        arre[j + 1] <- temp; // Insertar el elemento en su posición correcta
    FinPara
    
    // Imprimir arreglo ordenado
    Para i <- 0 Hasta N-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "Después: ", arre[i];
    FinPara
FinProceso



Estoy utilizando arreglos con índice en 1

Precisamente por eso es el problema,  como el primer índice en maruga es 1 y tu condición era  Mientras (j > 1), nunca llegas al primer elemento porque el último que lo cumple es 2, porque 2>1.

En PSeInt sé que anda, el problema es Maruga Script. Dice Mientras (j >= 0) Y (arre[j] > temp) Hacer Se requiere de una expresión ordinal

y si le pones j>0?

Maruga Script marca error también. Seguramente sea un error de Maruga
