Error en algoritmo de inserción
Tengo este código en lenguaje SL que pretende implementar el algoritmo por inserción de elementos de una lista
programa OrdenarArreglo
constantes
    N = 12 // Número total de elementos
variables
    arre : matriz[N] numerico
    i, j, temp : numerico
inicio
    // Inicializar el arreglo
    arre[1] = 5
    arre[2] = 3
    arre[3] = 0
    arre[4] = 2
    arre[5] = 4
    arre[6] = 1
    arre[7] = 0
    arre[8] = 5
    arre[9] = 2
    arre[10] = 3
    arre[11] = 1
    arre[12] = 4
    
    cls()

    // Imprimir arreglo original
    desde i = 1 hasta N {
        imprimir("Antes: ", arre[i],"\n")
    }
    
    imprimir("\n")    
    
    // Algoritmo de ordenamiento por inserción
    desde i = 2 hasta N {
        temp = arre[i]  // Guardar el valor actual
        j = i - 1       // Comenzar a comparar con el elemento anterior
        
        // Mover elementos de arre[1..i-1] que son mayores que temp
        mientras (j >= 1) {
            si (arre[j] > temp) {
                arre[j + 1] = arre[j] // Mover el elemento hacia adelante
                j = j - 1             // Mover hacia atrás
            sino
                j = -1
                    
            }
        }
        
     // Insertar el elemento en su posición correcta
        // Solo insertamos si j es -1, significa que hemos encontrado la posición
        si (j == -1) {
            arre[1] = temp // Si j es -1, significa que temp es el más pequeño
        sino
            arre[j + 1] = temp // Insertar en la posición correcta
        }
    }

    // Imprimir arreglo ordenado
    desde i = 1 hasta N {
        imprimir("Después: ", arre[i], "\n")
    }
fin

El algoritmo funciona pero lo ordena mal. Debe ser con un mientras y un si separados

¿En qué se diferencia de la pregunta que hiciste ayer? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/627741/algoritmo-por-inserci%c3%b3n-en-c%c3%b3digo-sl

Uno compila, este no

¿Si el código no compila, como sabes que ordena mal?

Tengo otra duda.. si el arreglo tiene 12 posiciones, que pensas hacer con el elemento que sobra cuando insertas el nuevo?

Disculpa, los dos compilan, pero dan resultado incorrecto pero diferente

Tratarlo de incluir en el arreglo
